How do I convert string data to numerical data using Label Encoder?
I was trying to convert string data into numerical data in a CSV excel sheet. It kept giving me an error about previously unseen labels, so I searched it up and found that we can use Label Encoder to convert all these values to numeric. I created a list of all columns with string data that needed to be converted and put it in the encoder, however, it still gave me an error saying 'previously unseen labels'. So to check where the problem was I tried leaving out certain columns from the list, and it magically worked when I cleared all of it.
This is what I tried to do first. The 'cat_cols' contains only the columns that have string data in it.
cat_cols = ['sales_channel', 'trip_type', 'flight_day', 'route'] 
enc = LabelEncoder()
for col in cat_cols:
     xtrain[col] = df[col].astype('str')
     xtest[col] = df[col].astype('str')

     xtrain[col] = enc.fit_transform(xtrain[col])
     xtest[col] = enc.transform(xtest[col])

When I tried this, Jupyter Lab kept giving me errors about unseen labels. Conversely, when I changed the code to this:
cat_cols = []#'sales_channel']#, 'trip_type', 'flight_day', 'route']

enc = LabelEncoder()

for col in cat_cols:
    xtrain[col] = df[col].astype('str')
    xtest[col] = df[col].astype('str')
    
    xtrain[col] = enc.fit_transform(xtrain[col])
    xtest[col] = enc.transform(xtest[col])

It worked perfectly fine, converting every single column. Can somebody please explain this to me?
Edit: Here is what the data looks like: The raw CSV file
Here's the error it is giving me: ValueError: y contains previously unseen label: PERVTE
I've tried it again, and the code has converted everything, except the 'booking_origin' column.
Here is a picture: Data after using Label Encoding
Why is it only leaving out this column?

Hi, welcome to SO! Your second example isn't doing anything, as you are iterating over an empty list (i.e. cat_cols = []). An empty list naturally has zero elements, so it's not converting anything, surely. For help with the actual problem, please add a [mre] and provide the full traceback for the error.

Hi!, I've added some screenshots which I hope make it clearer. The error seems to be with only one of the columns. All the rest has been converted.
Thanks a lot!

Please use OrdinalEncoder instead. With correct settings, it can handle cases where there are values in the test set that aren't in the train set. More details here: sklearn.LabelEncoder with never seen before values
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

# Create encoder
ordinal_encoder = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value',
                                 unknown_value=-1)

